# Вернуть фокус на вкладку

Tags: javascript

Пример: пользователь переходит из вкладки А на вкладку Б. При каком-то событии на вкладке А она должна становится активной.
Можно ли вернуть фокус на вкладку?

Comment: Вкладку в браузере или на табе?

Comment: Именно в браузере

Comment: нет, мне нужно возвращать фокус именно на вкладку, но которой происходит событие.

Comment: Я думаю максимум что вы можете- проиграть какой-нибудь звук на этой вкладке, чтобы привлечь внимание пользователя.

Comment: Для Chromenium и Mozilla пишите своё расширение и будет вам счастье. А больше ни как и никогда такого не будет. Если каждый сайт вам будет переключать вкладки - я думаю вам сильно понравится такое поведение.

Answer (score 0):

**это похоже на поведение вируса**, никто не хотел бы, чтобы его перенаправляли на вкладку с которой он хотел уйти.

Для этого в браузерах теперь есть "подписка на уведомления" (за это отвечают фоновые скрипты, воркеры). Если нужно "возвращать" пользователя, используются именно они, приложения реального времени, чаты и т.п. Но лучше всего работают отличные сервисы и контент от которого не хочется уходить.